# What is body parameter in youtube data api's operations?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am learning Youtube Data API with python.
I followed their [guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) and could able to understand what resources and their supported operations are. I got idea about `part` and `filed` parameter that passes in operations from same page.

e.g

```
    playlists_insert_response = youtube.playlists().insert(
       part="snippet,status",
       body=dict(
          snippet=dict(
             title="Test Playlist",
             description="A private playlist created with the YouTube API v3"
             ),
          status=dict(
             privacyStatus="private"
         )
       )
    ).execute()
```

In this example code we have to pass parameter into `insert()` 
possible parameters are `part` and `fields`. But some examples I saw body as parameter also. I could not understand that.

Could anyone tell me why we pass `body` parameter in operations? What actually it is?
I am following trying out understand example code from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube actually provides a kind of REST API, where every request is the HTTP request to some URL. The python client library you are using is just a frontend for this API, that hides actual HTTP requests behind function calls.

This `body` parameter in the python library allows you to specify HTTP request body. For example, to insert a playlist you need to provide [`playlist`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#resource) resource as a request body.

This parameter is here only for PUT and POST requests (inserts and updates), when you need to specify some resource content.

Comment: Thank you :)  
your answers helped me what I was trying to understand

Comment: @user3214243 So you accept my answer or I need to clarify something in more depth?

Comment: thank you, I have understood these parameters but I still have to understand youtube scopes and authentication process

Comment: @user3214243 Looks like you should post separated questions about this issues.

Comment: OK. If my answer was helpful consider accepting it by clicking to the huge check mark on the left.